# Typescript asking to pass props although being already passed by mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-props

This is my **ChildComponent** receiving **foo** prop from Redux.

```
interface InjectedProps {
  foo: string;
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<InjectedProps> = ({ foo, }) => (
    <div>
      {foo}
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): InjectedProps => ({
  foo: state.fooReducer.foo,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ChildComponent);
```

The **ChildComponent** is wrapped by a **ParentComponent**.

```
const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
);
```

**Typescript** is throwing an error to pass **foo** prop myself as `<ChildComponent foo="some value"/>` but I don't want to do that as it's being passed implicitly by Redux.

```
Property 'foo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<InjectedProps, "foo">'.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you installed `react-redux` typings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your amazing response. I have figured it out. Well, if you look at the export of **ChildComponent**.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ChildComponent);
```

The mistake that I did is that I specified **null** because **mapDispatchToProps** is not being used in this component. I changed it to `{}` and the typescript no more threw error.

So the **ChildComponent** export should be:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: i think you can omit that parameter completely: connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent); since you are not binding any dispatch actions

Comment: Yes I omitted that and it worked absolutely fine as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import your child component like this:

```
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
```

Also like others suggested install react-redux typings (yarn add @types/react-redux -D or npm install @types/react-redux -D).

If that doesn't work (it should, but if it doesnt) you can try this:

```
export default connect<InjectedProps>(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

You can specify typings manually to connect if it is not working automatically.